# how to get decoded string with "\" using base64 module

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I can not get the path right using base64 module as the expected output should be like

> C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\photos\photo.png

I printed in my previous approach variable `image_open` and I get the slashes but when I decode and encode it and try to print variable `image_file` after encoding it, it ends up giving me no slashes in between the path that is define...

```
import os
import base64
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTK,Image

def pick_photo():
    global image
    global image_file_name
    #label_path_of_photo = tk.StringVar()
    ask_path_of_photo = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "C:/Users/User _Name/Documents/photos/",
                                     title = "Open File",
                                     filetypes = (("PNG","*.png"),("JPG","*jpg"),("All file","*.*")))   

    image_file_name =os.path.abspath(ask_path_of_photo)
    image_open = Image.open(general_path_to_photo + image_file_name)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_open)
    image_show = tk.Label(root, image = image, textvariable = label_path_of_photo)
    image_show.grid(row = 0, column = 3, rowspan = 3, columnspan = 6, padx = 15, pady = 25)    

    path_decode(image_file_name)

def path_decode(image_file_name):
        decoded_path_of_image = base64.b64decode(image_file_name)
        print(decoded_path_of_image)
        encodig_path = base64.b64encode(decoded_path_of_image)
        print(encodig_path)
```

I expected the output be printed with as slash as it is defined (in the **io.path.abspath(ask_path_of_photo)**  I print it returns fine but I don't get the slash in the printed string after encoding it
If any other error is riced else this Kindly help me to figure it out that too

Comment: do you get error ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: create minimal working code with your problem so everyone could run it and see problem.

Comment: I think you use `base64` in wrong way. You should first create `filename.encode('utf-8')` next use `b64encode`, not `b64decode`. And then for your path you get string `b'QzpcVXNlcnNcVXNlcl9OYW1lXERvY3VtZW50c1xwaG90b3NccGhvdG8ucG5n'` . Now using `b64decode` adn `.decode('utf-8)` you can get your path back.

Comment: Nope no error was found in it just the **print function** not returning the desire output
I just want to print the whole path of the photo by `encoding and decoding`

Comment: @furas thanks  for your interest and assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you use `base64` in wrong way.

You should first create `filename.encode('utf-8')` and next use `b64encode`, not `b64decode`. And then you get string in base64.

Now using `b64decode` and `.decode('utf-8)` you can get back your path

```
import base64

def path_decode(filename):

    bytes_name = filename.encode('utf-8')
    encodig_path = base64.b64encode(bytes_name)
    print(encodig_path)

    bytes_name = base64.b64decode(encodig_path)
    filename = bytes_name.decode('utf-8')
    print(filename)


image_file_name = r'C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\photos\photo.png'
path_decode(image_file_name)
```

Result

```
b'QzpcVXNlcnNcVXNlcl9OYW1lXERvY3VtZW50c1xwaG90b3NccGhvdG8ucG5n'
C:\Users\User_Name\Documents\photos\photo.png
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know where I am going wrong @furas